# Android PHP MySQL with Volley, can't register user, getting blank Toast

Tags: java, android

I'm creating registration form on my localhost, form works as it should, I can register user when using Postman, but when I try to register user from my Android app I only get blank Toast message and user is not registered.

Here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private EditText editTextUsername, editTextEmail, editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonRegister;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == buttonRegister){
            registerUser();
        }
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering user...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.URL_REGISTER,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };


        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);


    }
```

Constants.java

```
public class Constants {
    private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://192.168.56.2/Android/v1/";

    public static final String URL_REGISTER = ROOT_URL+"registerUser.php";
}
```

RequestHandler.java

```
public class RequestHandler {
    private static RequestHandler mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private RequestHandler(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public static synchronized RequestHandler getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new RequestHandler(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your `response` ?

Comment: It looks like the response doenst contain the field `message` or it is empty. add an log output for your json response from server

Comment: Your system and mobile device are connected on same wifi?

Comment: Same wifi, uploaded files to a live server now, not getting any toasts or error messages, the user is just not inserted into database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all give Internet permission to your project.

Then use a php script like this one adapted to your needs:

```
<?php

    $connect = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.gr", "u305474665_xxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "u305474665_xxxxx");



     $name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : '';

     $username = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : '';

     $age = isset($_POST["age"]) ? $_POST["age"] : '';

     $password = isset($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST["password"] : '';


    function registerUser()   {

        global $connect, $name, $age, $username, $password;

        $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO User (name,username,age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $username, $age, $password);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_close($statement);  

    };

    function usernameAvailable() {

        global $connect, $username;
        $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ?"); 
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
        $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_close($statement); 

        if ($count < 1){

            return true; 

        }
        else {

            return false; 

        }
    };

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    if (usernameAvailable()){

         registerUser();
        $response["success"] = true;  

    }

    print_r(json_encode($response));
?>
```

Last but very important: Define a retry policy Recursively on your error Listener.